# Assign In SELECT Command for MySQL Not working

Tags: mysql, sql, function, select

I am trying to assign the @lastupd variable. as in below line:

```sql
select @lastupd := max(`last_edited_time`) 
  from flyspray_comments where task_id = taskID;
```

But mysql give me error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'BEGIN
>
> set @lastupd = 0;   select @lastupd := max(`last_edited_time`) from
>   flys' at line 2

The code:

```sql
delimiter   $$

use flyspray $$

CREATE function last_upd_time(taskID INT)
BEGIN
  set @lastupd = 0;
  select @lastupd := max(`last_edited_time`) from flyspray_comments where task_id = taskID;
  RETURN @lastupd;
END
$$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: post more /full code, you can see it says you have error near BEGIN.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) is all about syntax error

Answer (score 3):

1. Your immediate error has nothing to do with assignment. It is caused by the invalid definition of the function. You're missing mandatory `RETURNS` clause which indicates the return type of the function. See [`CREATE FUNCTION Syntax`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html).
2. There is no need to use a variable in your case, less a user(session) variable. Just `RETURN` the result of the query.
3. And since you may use the only statement there is no need in a `BEGIN ... END` block and changing `DELIMITER`

That being said a streamlined and working version of your function may look like

```
CREATE FUNCTION last_upd_time(_task_id INT) 
RETURNS DATETIME  -- mandatory clause
RETURN            -- just return the result of the query
(
  SELECT MAX(last_edited_time) 
    FROM flyspray_comments 
   WHERE task_id = _task_id
); -- use default delimiter since it's a one-statement function
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/088a5e/2)** demo

---

Now, if you'd like to use a variable for some reason then

1. use a local instead of user(session) one.
2. assign a value with either `SET` or `SELECT ... INTO` syntax.

It may look like

```sql
DECLARE lastupd DATETIME DEFAULT NULL; -- or 0
SET lastupd = 
(
  SELECT MAX(last_edited_time) 
    FROM flyspray_comments 
   WHERE task_id = _task_id
);
```

or

```sql
DECLARE lastupd DATETIME DEFAULT NULL; -- 0
SELECT MAX(last_edited_time) 
  INTO lastupd
  FROM flyspray_comments 
 WHERE task_id = _task_id;
```

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?